# mongoid combination of any_of and between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid4

I need to achieve something like:

```
queryable.any_of(
      between(:average_nightly_min_price,  [10,100]),
      between(:average_nightly_max_price,  [110,1100])
  )
```

is it possible using the combination of `any_of` and `between`. Or any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queryable.any_of(
  queryable.between(:average_nightly_min_price,  [10,100]).selector,
  queryable.between(:average_nightly_max_price,  [110,1100]).selector
)
```

It does not work if the queryable is embeded.

For ruby versions prior 2.0:

```
queryable.any_of(
      queryable.between(average_nightly_min_price => [10,100]).selector,
      queryable.between(average_nightly_max_price => [110,1100]).selector
    )
```

Comment: When trying this, using Mongoid 4, I am getting the error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)`. My query is `Gift.any_of(Gift.between(:gift_units_count, [0,1]).selector, Gift.between(:gift_units_count, [10,100]).selector)`

Answer (score 0):

I also got an `ArgumentError` (like @christofferjoergensen), but with `mongoid 3.1.5`

Using the hashrocket syntax instead of passing two arguments solved it:

```
queryable.any_of(
  queryable.between(:average_nightly_min_price => [10,100]).selector,
  queryable.between(:average_nightly_max_price => [110,1100]).selector
)
```