# How to combine combine any_of with between in Mongoid 4?

Tags: ruby, mongoid, mongoid4

I have read in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369414/mongoid-combination-of-any-of-and-between) this you can combine `any_of` with `between` like this:

```
webshop = Webshop.first

webshop.orders.any_of(
  webshop.orders.between(:datetime_pending, [Time.zone.now-7.days, Time.zone.now]).selector, # An error is raised here.
  webshop.orders.between(:datetime,         [Time.zone.now-7.days, Time.zone.now]).selector
)
```

But When trying this query, using Mongoid 4, I am getting the error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1).
/Users/christoffer/project/vendor/gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/origin-1.1.0/lib/origin/selectable.rb:63:in `between'
/Users/christoffer/project/vendor/gems/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-b91705b0ded8/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb:413:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/christoffer/project/vendor/gems/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-b91705b0ded8/lib/mongoid/scopable.rb:238:in `with_scope'
/Users/christoffer/project/vendor/gems/ruby/2.0.0/bundler/gems/mongoid-b91705b0ded8/lib/mongoid/relations/referenced/many.rb:412:in `method_missing'
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: on what method? Please add the full error.

Comment: Apologies. A full stacktrace has now been put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [Queryable#between](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/selection.html) takes a hash (a key with a range value).

Have you tried passing that instead of an array?

```
webshop = Webshop.first
now = Time.zone.now
seven_days = now - 7.days
webshop_orders = webshop.orders

webshop_orders.any_of(
  webshop_orders.between(datetime_pending: seven_days..now).selector,
  webshop_orders.between(datetime:         seven_days..now).selector
)
```